# Añadir marcador a mapa con javascript en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-v3

junto con saludar les comento mi siguiente problema:

Tengo un mapa de google maps en javascript para una app de delivery, la idea es trazar una ruta entre el cliente y el local para luego poder mostrar donde esta el delivery en tiempo real.
Les dejo lo que he realizado hasta ahora en codepen: https://codepen.io/Maikel-Yordan/pen/wvRBQQN

Mi idea es poder añadir un marcador y que se actualice cada 3 segundos, he probado con muchas opciones

dentro del initmap cree una funcion para que se actualice cada 3 segundos y estaba creando otra funcion "addMarker" pero de ninguna forma me ha funcionado que se añada el marcador.

```
setInterval(function mapload(){
    
                $.ajax({
                            type: "POST", 
                            url: 'location.php',
                           // data: form_data,
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                
                           // var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON
                                var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
                                for (var i in json_obj) 
                                {  
                                    addMarker(json_obj[i].la, json_obj[i].lo, 'REPARTIDOR');
                                
                                }
                            },
                            dataType: "json"//set to JSON    
                        })    
    
   
  },3000);
```

esta era la funcion addmarker pero me da errores, me base en otro sitio web para realizar la funcion.

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                        bounds.extend(pt);
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: pt,
                            draggable: true,
                            raiseOnDrag: true,
                            icon: icon,
                            map: map
                        });
                         markersArray.push(marker);
                        var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: info,
                            maxWidth: 600
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                            if (currentPopup != null) {
                                currentPopup.close();
                                currentPopup = null;
                            }
                            popup.open(map, marker);
                            currentPopup = popup;
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                            map.panTo(center);
                            currentPopup = null;
                        });
                    }
```

alguna idea de como actualizar el marcador y añadirlo cada 3 segundos ?

Edicion. He logrado agregar un marcado en un punto especifico, pero no puedo actualizar la posicion de ese marcador sin actualizar el navegador o agregar otro marcador, pero quedarian muchos marcadores al finalizar.

```
    let map;
    async function initMap() {

      const position = { lat: -33.474688, lng: -70.748728 };
  //@ts-ignore
      const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
      const { AdvancedMarkerView } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
      const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: position,
        mapId: "DELIVERY",
      });

      directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);

      const marker = new AdvancedMarkerView({
        map: map,
        position: position,
        title: "Uluru",
      });

    }

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
      const selectedMode = "DRIVING";

      directionsService
      .route({
        origin: { lat: -33.47193176506123, lng: -70.75275060085394 },
        destination: { lat: -33.48134525066978, lng: -70.74360779286403 },
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
      })
      .then((response) => {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      })
      .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
    }

    initMap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa ruta de ejemplo casi pasa por mi casa!!!

Con [setPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker?hl=es-419#Marker.setPosition) puede setear y actualizar la posición de un marcador.

Me parece que tu página que hace de API `location.php` es la que debes preocuparte. Te recomiendo:

- Usar `fetch` en lugar de `jQuery`, que ya estamos en el 2023
- Usar `GET` en lugar de `POST` (si bien, cualquiera sirve, GET es para traer datos (que es lo que tu quieres) y POST es para insertar)
- Debes enviar un dato que identifique al repartidor, porque si tienes más de uno, no te funciona. En el ejemplo yo puse una `id`
- En mi ejemplo yo supuse lo siguiente, a `location.php` le enviamos una `id` en la URL y nos retorna un JSON con la posición actual Ejemplo: `{lat: 34.23, lng: -74.343}`, además cuando tu sistema detecta que el repartidor ya entregó el paquete, esto debería entregar `null` o `false` para que el mapa dejara de seguir al repartidor

Aquí el ejemplo, notar que hay código adicional solo para fines de probar que el marcador se actualiza, que es el fondo de la pregunta

```js
//SOLO PARA TEST ==================================
let puntos;
let index=0;
function GetTestPuntos(ruta){
  puntos = ruta["routes"][0]["overview_path"];
}
//=================================================


let intervalo;
async function initMap() {
  const id=1; //id del repartidor
  const INTERVALO=3000;

  
  const desde = { lat: -33.47193176506123, lng: -70.75275060085394 };
  const hasta = { lat: -33.48134525066978, lng: -70.74360779286403 };
  
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: desde
  });

  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: desde, map: map})

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  const ruta = await GetRuta(directionsService, desde, hasta);
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(ruta);
  
  await GetTestPuntos(ruta); //SOLO PARA TEST
  
  intervalo = setInterval(Update,INTERVALO,marker,id);

}



async function GetRuta(directionsService, desde, hasta) {
  const selectedMode = "DRIVING";

  return await directionsService
    .route({
      origin: desde,
      destination: hasta,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
    });
}

async function GetPosition(id){
// return await fetch('location.php?id='+id).then(r=>r.json()); //ALGO ASÏ DEBERIA SER LA LLAMADA A LA API
 
 //SOLO PARA TEST
 return new Promise(r=> r(puntos[index++]));
 
}

async function Update(marker, id){
  const newpos = await GetPosition(id);
  
  if(!newpos){
    clearInterval(intervalo); //FIN
  }else{
     marker.setPosition(newpos);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHMRByPyYLkQoiw5IfbGN4cKXLEZIj6CQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Que chico el mundo no! yo vivo tambien por parte de la ruta jaja.
Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, me estaba complicando un poco ya... ahora me funciono a la perfección.
Lo del ID y todo ya lo tenia considerado, te agradezco por darte el tiempo de analizarlo bien igual.
Tuve un problema con el json en Javascript pero pude solucionarlo sin problema.